# PHP and MYSQL displaying 1 record of multiple Name

Tags: php, mysql, database, image

i am designing one model website which have different events. I have store the image in a database table name image. Now my question is how do i display one record for one event out of many records? For example : the user will upload multiple events image in same image but with same event name. Now i have to display single image per event.

The name of table is images it got filed like imageID, imageName, imageType, eventName, imagePath

how do i create an sql statement where it print different event name and image

Comment: Make your question more informative such as give your table structure, give the code that you tried with etc.

Comment: How about picking up an image at random every time a user visits the page for a particular event?

Comment: Hi Aziz thanks for the reply but what i want is i want to show 1 image of each event.

Comment: Which image though? as in what is the criteria to select the image?

Comment: I want to create a page called event and want to get all the events form database where the field name is eventName. But in the db there multiple record for same event. So, how do i get one event name out of many?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not clear. 
Hope this query may help.

```
 select * from images 
 where eventName='name'
 group by eventName
```

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on the answer by @learner:

This code:

```
SELECT * FROM images  
WHERE eventName = 'name' 
GROUP BY eventName
```

Selects a random row from all the possible rows that apply.
If you want some control over **which** image gets selected, you need to use a `HAVING` clause (or simular construct).

This code will select the image that was added most recently.

```
SELECT * FROM images  
WHERE eventName = 'name' 
GROUP BY eventName 
HAVING id = MAX(id)       <<-- assuming id is an auto_incrementing primary key
//HAVING date_added = MAX(date_added)  <<-- use this instead if you have an added_date
```

If you are only ever interested in a single image for a single event you can also do:

```
SELECT * FROM images
WHERE eventname = 'name'
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0;
```